# how to detect the child element change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

the aside elements inside the parent div will get add or remove/replace dynamically. I want to detect the change and call the method.

```
<div id = "hello" >
<aside class="item">
    <a href="abc"><img src="abc" title="abc" /></a>
</aside>
<aside class="item">
    <a href="abc2"><img src="abc2" title="abc2" /></a>
</aside>
<aside class="item">
    <a href="abc1"><img src="abc1" title="abc1" /></a>
</aside>
</div >
```

expected result:
call a method on change of child elements.

Comment: What about calling a function on add/remove?

Comment: you are trying to change <img> tag?

Comment: each aside elements behaves like a slider, so when it gets added or removed by adobe target, the pagination and some other bindings are mismatching. those data in the separate function, I want to trigger the method on changing the aside elements.